# Transform(Set SCNNode on sufrace ) SCNNode with SCNMaterial without change orientation for SCNMaterial contains image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, arkit

Anyone know how to transform SCNMaterial to surface without change orientation of SCNMaterial contains an image?

I want to create ARKit SCNNode with contains an image and then it transforms to surface cause I want to show the image on a surface area on the selected position

I am using following code to transform my SCNNode

```
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(Width), height: CGFloat(Height))
let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage.init(named: “imgName”)
        let matirials:[SCNMaterial] = [material]
        planeGeometry.materials = matirials
let rectNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
var transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(transform, Float(orientation), 0, 1, 0)

        rectNode.transform  = transform

self.addChildNode(rectNode)
self.position = position
```

An issue in the above code:
Node transform successfully but it’s flip my SCNMaterial image randomly based on orientation.

So any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The material transform can be adjusted by `contentsTransform` of `SCNMaterialProperty`

`material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4.SCNMatrix4Identity`

Or if you just need adjust the mirrored image, you can use either

`material.diffuse.wrapS = .mirror` or
`material.diffuse.wrapT = .mirror`

Comment: Thank you so much for your instant answer but it's not helpful to me. 
I have tried both ways to mirror material contains image but it's not flipped and issue remain same.

Comment: Posting your efforts may lead to an answer.